# how to show a success message after navigation and when opening new screen?

Tags: react-navigation, react-native-flash-message

after login success i need to show a message that the operation was successful on the nextpage
thanks for help

```
import {showMessage} from "react-native-flash-message";
import { NavigationContainer ,useFocusEffect} from '@react-navigation/native';

const MainScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
    const { userId, email } = route.params;
    useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
            showMessage({
                message: "Welcome mr "+email,
                type: "success",
              });
              
        }, [])

      );
      return(
        <View>
            <Text>aaaa</Text>
        </View>
      )
}

export default MainScreen;
```

Comment: Hi,  
I have to ask, what is "useFocusEffect" , and why would you choose to call the "useCallback"?.

Comment: allows you to run an effect on focus and clean it up when the screen becomes unfocused

Answer (score 0):

You can use useEffect for this :-

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
useEffect(() => {
   showMessage({
      message: "Welcome mr "+email,
      type: "success",
   });
 }, []);
```

Comment: if i used the useEffect i think it renderd after any change